# Custom cursor and customized context menu in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

My Flex 3 application uses a custom cursor and has to show a customized context menu when the user performs a right click. The problem is the customized menu is shown only when the default arrow cursor is shown. When I change it to the custom cursor, the standard context menu appears instead of the customized one.

Is there a way to have both custom cursor and customized context menu in a flash application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customized context menu will appear as long as the custom cursor doesn't cover mouse's hot spot. In other words, the graphic for the custom cursor should be displayed at 1 pixel offset (at least) from (0, 0) point of the original mouse pointer.

Comment: It's been a week without any solutions for my problem. I'm posting the two workarounds I've found meanwhile. New solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26552

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the official bug entry. However I was hoping of some kind of a solution or a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use CursorManager for showing the custom cursor. Hide the default mouse pointer and draw a cursor manually instead. I've posted detailed steps in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111533/change-mouse-cursor-to-a-bitmap-flex-4/3116814#3116814).