# Change mouse cursor to a bitmap (Flex 4)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In Flex 4, how can I change the cursor to a Bitmap image determined at **runtime**? All the examples I've seen use CursorManager.setCursor to set the cursor to a class specified at compile time.

What I want to do is change the cursor to a bitmap whose bitmapData is determined by the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package cursor
{
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.PixelSnapping;

import mx.core.BitmapAsset;

public class RuntimeBitmap1 extends BitmapAsset
{

    public static var staticBitmapData:BitmapData;

    public function RuntimeBitmap1()
    {
        super(staticBitmapData);
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(50, 50, false, 0x88888888);
RuntimeBitmap1.staticBitmapData = bitmapData;
cursorManager.setCursor(RuntimeBitmap1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to draw a UIComponent as a cursor.

I managed it using a combination of Maxims answer and this [Flex Cookbox article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=1682). The only change I had to make to Maxim answer was a s follows:

```
public function RuntimeBitmap1()
{
    super(RuntimeBitmap1.staticBitmapData);
}
```

Otherwise staticBitmapData came through as null in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few simple steps to change the default cursor with a bitmap image:

1. Create your cursor of type Bitmap by using an image of your choice. You can also set the bitmapData dynamically during runtime.

   ```
   var DEFAULT_CURSOR_IMAGE : Class;
   var myCursorBitmap : Bitmap;
   ...
   myCursorBitmap = new DEFAULT_CURSOR_IMAGE();
   ```
2. Register to receive mouse move events and update cursor position accordingly.

   ```
   function onMouseMove(event : MouseEvent) : void
   {
      myCursorBitmap.x = event.localX;
      myCursorBitmap.y = event.localY;
   }
   ```
3. Hide the real cursor by using Mouse.hide().
4. Show your custom cursor. You may update cursor shape later by setting bitmapData dynamically.

   ```
   addChild(myCursorBitmap);
   ...
   myCursorBitmap.bitmapData = myNewCursor;
   ```

To restore the default cursor, remove your cursor bitmap from the stage and call Mouse.show().

Comment: This is a Flex project, so I can't addChild to the main mxml class.

Comment: @justkevin: yes, you're right - in this case you'll have to place it in a UIComponent.